# Javascript code to get last remaining row of the table body and hide the table once that row gets deleted

Tags: javascript, dom-manipulation

```js
class Library {
    constructor(par1, par2, par3){
        this.serialNumber = par1;
        this.bookTitle = par2;
        this.author = par3;        
    }
}



class Book {
    addBookToBookList(par4){
        const table = document.getElementById('subContainer'),
            tbody = document.getElementById('tbody'),
            subContainer = document.getElementById('subContainer'),
            clearAll = document.getElementById('clear');         

        
            let tr = document.createElement('tr');
                tr.classList = 'listItem';
                tr.innerHTML = `<td class="underListItem" id="data1">${par4.serialNumber}</td>
                <td class="underListItem" id="data2">${par4.bookTitle}</td>
                <td class="underListItem" id="data3">${par4.author}<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></a></td>`;

                subContainer.style.display = 'table';

                tbody.appendChild(tr);

                clearAll.style.display = 'block';        
    }
    

    clearInputFields(){
        document.getElementById('bookTitle').value ='';
        document.getElementById('author').value ='';
        document.getElementById('serialNum').value ='';
    }


    message(msg, color){
        let header = document.getElementById('header'),
            p = document.createElement('p');
            p.classList = 'p';
            header.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', p);
            p.style.display = 'block';
            p.innerText = msg;
            p.style.backgroundColor = color;
        setTimeout(()=>{
            p.style.display = 'none';
        }, 1500)
    }
    
}




    




document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e){

    const bookTitle = document.getElementById('bookTitle').value;
    const author = document.getElementById('author').value;
    const serialNum = document.getElementById('serialNum').value;    
    

    let book = new Library(serialNum, bookTitle, author);

    let addBook = new Book();

    if(bookTitle === ''){
        addBook.message('Please provide Book Title!!', 'rgb(243, 93, 93)');
    }else if(author === ''){
        addBook.message('Please provide Author!!', 'rgb(243, 93, 93)');
    }else if(serialNum === ''){
        addBook.message('Please provide Serial Number!!', 'rgb(243, 93, 93)')
    }else if(bookTitle !== '' && author !== '' && serialNum !== ''){

        addBook.addBookToBookList(book);

        addBook.message('New Book Added!!', 'rgb(46, 216, 69)');

        addBook.clearInputFields();
    }
    e.preventDefault()
})




document.getElementById('subContainer').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    
    if(e.target.classList.contains('fa-times-circle')){
        e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
        document.getElementById('subContainer').style.display = 'none';
    }    
})
```

```js
document.getElementById('subContainer').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    
    if(e.target.classList.contains('fa-times-circle')){
        e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
        document.getElementById('subContainer').style.display = 'none';
    }    
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <title>Book List</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id="container">        
        
        <table id="subContainer">
            <thead>
                <tr id="list">
                    <th class="listTitle" width="15%">Sl No.</th>
                    <th class="listTitle">Title</th>
                    <th class="listTitle" width="40%">Author</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tbody">
                <tr class="listItem">
                    <td class="underListItem">Item 1</td>
                    <td class="underListItem">Item 2</td>
                    <td class="underListItem">Item 3<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="listItem">
                    <td class="underListItem">Item 1</td>
                    <td class="underListItem">Item 2</td>
                    <td class="underListItem">Item 3<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="listItem">
                    <td class="underListItem">Item 1</td>
                    <td class="underListItem">Item 2</td>
                    <td class="underListItem">Item 3<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>    
    
    

    <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

> Trying to get the last remaining row of the table body to hide the table once I delete the row. Situation of now is whenever I am deleting a row the whole table gets hidden and reappear if I dynamically add any row.
> I want its solution in Javascript.
> Updated the javascript code here..let me know for anything else.

Comment: The last paragraph of your question: it is not true that "the whole table gets deleted". It gets hidden. You can verify this by inspection via the dev console. If you don't want to hide the table, then don't do `style.display = 'none';`. It is not clear what you are asking now.

Comment: I want to hide the table once the last remaining row gets deleted and not before.
Can you help me out with this?

Comment: "*reappear if I dynamically add any row*" - please show the code for that as well

Comment: done..please check..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the `rows.length` property of the `tbody` element.

NB: I would also use `closest` to find the `tr` element to remove.

```js
let table = document.getElementById('subContainer');
document.getElementById('subContainer').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if(e.target.classList.contains('fa-times-circle')){
        e.target.closest("tr").remove();
        if (table.tBodies[0].rows.length == 0) table.style.display = 'none';
    }    
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <title>Book List</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id="container">        
        
        <table id="subContainer">
            <thead>
                <tr id="list">
                    <th class="listTitle" width="15%">Sl No.</th>
                    <th class="listTitle">Title</th>
                    <th class="listTitle" width="40%">Author</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tbody">
                <tr class="listItem">
                    <td class="underListItem">Item 1</td>
                    <td class="underListItem">Item 2</td>
                    <td class="underListItem">Item 3<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="listItem">
                    <td class="underListItem">Item 1</td>
                    <td class="underListItem">Item 2</td>
                    <td class="underListItem">Item 3<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="listItem">
                    <td class="underListItem">Item 1</td>
                    <td class="underListItem">Item 2</td>
                    <td class="underListItem">Item 3<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>    
    
    

    <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```